# Unique Constraint group similar values

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, constraints

Let's say I have a database with columns `name`, `last_name` and `type`

They're all strings, though type can only be `TYPE_A`, `TYPE_B` or `TYPE_C`

I want a row in the database to be `Unique` when `name` and `last_name` already exist.

Additionally, I want `TYPE_A` and `TYPE_B` to be treated as the same in uniqueness and `TYPE` C to be treated differently. Essentially, I want either `TYPE_A` or `TYPE_B` to be seen as `TYPE_A_B`. I don't want to modify any values already present in the database.

I only want to add this constraint to an already existing database, how do I do this?

(I'm using Postgres)

For example: `(name, last_name, type)`

Valid:

`John, Doe Type A`

`John, Doe Type C`

Invalid (Unique constraint violation)

`John, Cena Type C`

`John, Doe Type A` <-

`John, Doe Type B` <-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres' constraints do not support expressions, but you can achieve the same goal with a *unique index*:

```
create table mytable (name text, last_name text, type text);

create unique index myidx on mytable (
    name, 
    last_name, 
    ( case when type in ('Type A', 'Type B') then 'Type AB' else type end )
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lza_Ws15)

```
insert into mytable (name, last_name, type) values ('John', 'Doe', 'Type A');
-- ok

insert into mytable (name, last_name, type) values ('John', 'Doe', 'Type C');
-- ok

insert into mytable (name, last_name, type) values ('John', 'Doe', 'Type B');
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "myidx"
DETAIL:  Key (name, last_name, (
CASE
    WHEN type = ANY (ARRAY['Type A'::text, 'Type B'::text]) THEN 'Type AB'::text
    ELSE type
END))=(John, Doe, Type AB) already exists.
```

---

If you wanted to enforce unicity on types A/B only, ignoring other types, then you would use a filtering unique index instead:

```
create unique index myidx 
    on mytable (name, last_name)
    where(type in ('Type A', 'Type B'));
```

Comment: I have another question for you @GMB if you don't mind. I'd like values other than TYPE_A and TYPE_B not to be treated as unique. is this possible? <3

Answer (score 2):

Create a functional unique index:

```
create unique index idx on mytable 
(
  name,
  last_name,
  (case when type in ('Type A', 'Type B') then 'TYPE_A_B' else type end)
);
```

(The additional parentheses around the `CASE` expression are mandatory here.)

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/rIzYyU-n